# How do I index and save the strings in adjacent rows in a df in R?

Tags: r, indexing

I have limited r knowledge and would like to run such a task in a big data frame:
Data frame consists of binary answers of 1 and 2, and on the adjacent row the reasoning why the person chose that answer:

| A_answer1 | reasoning1 | B_answer2 | reasoning2 | A_answer3 | reasoning3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "some statement" | 2 | "some reasoning" | 1 | "yes" |
| 2 | "another statement" | 1 | "some sentence" | 1 | "because of x" |

As the first task I want to have 2 df of strings, if the answer is one, saving the adjacent string to a df. if the answer is 2, saving the string to another df. In the end I want to have a df1:

"some statement"
"yes"
"some sentence"
"because of x"

and df2:

"some reasoning"
"another statement"

I managed to do the first one with this loop:

```
drive <- list() #create an empty list
yield <- list()
c <- 0

for(i in seq(3,ncol(df),2)) {
  c<- c+1
  temp <- df[i+1]
  drive[[c]] <- temp[df[i]==1]
  yield[[c]] <- temp[df[i]==2]
}


lapply(drive, function(x) write.table( data.frame(x), 'drive.csv'  , append= T, sep=',' ))
lapply(yield, function(x) write.table( data.frame(x), 'yield.csv'  , append= T, sep=',' ))
```

As the second task I would like to have 2 df of strings per condition. Answer 1 and answer 3 belong to the same condition "A". I would like to extract strings from condition A per answer group 1 and 2.
so in this case what I want is
df1_A:
"same statement"
"yes"
"because of x"

and df2_A:
"another statement"

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Could you please show the expected results? Seeing can be easier to understand than reading the explanation. And to make things clearer, maybe have the example `"string"`s be different so we can tell which one is which in the desired result.

Comment: Hi Gregor, I have changed the strings and added what I wish to have as outcomes. Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We can stack your data up in a long format so that it is easier to work with:

```
library(dplyr)

# identify answer and reason columns
answer_cols = grep("answer", names(df), value = T)
reason_cols = grep("reason", names(df), value = T)

# make long data
long_df = data.frame(
  answers = unlist(df[answer_cols]),
  reasons = unlist(df[reason_cols])
)
#            answers           reasons
# A_answer11       1    some statement
# A_answer12       2 another statement
# B_answer21       2    some reasoning
# B_answer22       1     some sentence
# A_answer31       1               yes
# A_answer32       1      because of x

# filter the long data to get your results
long_df %>% filter(answers == 1)
#            answers        reasons
# A_answer11       1 some statement
# B_answer22       1  some sentence
# A_answer31       1            yes
# A_answer32       1   because of x

long_df %>% filter(answers == 2)
#            answers           reasons
# A_answer12       2 another statement
# B_answer21       2    some reasoning
```